# Can't get mcrypt to work on OS X High Sierra and PHP 7.1

Tags: php, macos, mcrypt

I need to use a Wordpress 3rd party plugin that uses mcrypt. mcrypt is not available as default in my environment (OSX High Sierra and PHP 7.1) (and I know that it is deprecated...) so I installed it with PECL. The installed mcrypt.so file was created in this location:

/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/

I have added the following to my php.ini:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mcrypt.so
```

And after that

```
php -i | grep mcrypt
```

returns

```
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
```

And

```
php -m | grep mcrypt
```

returns

```
mcrypt
```

To me this means that php now can use mcrypt.

I restart Apache, but still get a fatal error:

```
**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in /User.....
```

And displaying a page with

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

does NOT show mcrypt among the modules. But IT IS the correct php.ini that is used. So to me this means that php can use mcrypt when started from the command line but not when used from Apache.

I also tried to uncomment the line

```
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

in httpd.conf, and restart apache, but 
the result is the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe Apache uses different PHP? Add .http file with just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check whether there is `mcrypt`. Bear in mind that `mcrypt` is deprecated in 7.1 and removed in 7.1 http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php

Comment: This might be a better fit on wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Damian. That is what I did and the result from phpinfo() shows no sign of mcrypt but also that it is the correct php.ini that is used.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, this was a problem with Apache+PHP. I re-installed both Apache and PHP following the advice from here https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-upgrade-homebrew (which since has been updated for the new version OSX 10.14 Mojave) and here: https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-mojave-apache-multiple-php-versions

I site from the former site:

> The cleanest way to migrate from the old brew formulae to the new pecl
>   package approach is to remove everything PHP-related and reinstall
>   with the new instructions.